# A short story about baby on/off switch

Tags: story-identification

I read this short story about 30 years ago. Maybe from Pohl or Asimov.

A mother describes having an on/off switch installed on her baby and it's the greatest thing ever<sup>1</sup>.

They can go to work, they can interact with the kid whenever they want, etc. But although the mother is enthusiastic, the story has a strong icky factor.

---

<sub>1</sub> <sub>As a new father I can believe that!</sub>

Comment: http://dailysciencefiction.com/science-fiction/future-societies/stacey-danielle-lepper/back-in-my-day is too recent, 2012, but it matches up surprisingly well.

Comment: I have often told my wife I wished we could pause our children. Once again, a sci-fi great of yesteryear has stolen my idea, decades before I had it.

Comment: Time traveling idea snatchers!

Comment: The re is a movie ZPG , there is scene were the woman was ask to switch off the baby. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069530/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl

Comment: @Bigben59: I don't own the movie in question, and I was not the original querent, but it seems like a big jump to go from installing a switch on an extant baby to a movie where the baby comes with an off-switch because it's a robot.

Comment: Wow, that sounds familiar. I would swear that I read this in my mid-80s Science-Fiction Literature class. That would mean it was: a) written before then, and b) by a famous golden-age SF author...

Comment: Children of Tomorrow maybe? It's not that the kids have an off switch, the parents are financially constrained, so are keeping their kids young artificially so as to lengthen their childhood so as to be able to earn more money to buy more things so as to fill the kids' childhood w/ more toys.

Comment: This sounds a lot like "PauseTime" by Mary Soon Lee. It was published in 2000 though. And the mother is not enthusiastic about pausing her kid. Available online at http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/pausetime/. Also in audio on the StarShipSofa Podcast episode 330 http://www.starshipsofa.com/blog/2014/03/25/starshipsofa-no-330-leah-cypess-and-mary-soon-lee/

Comment: It reminded me of 'The Grandfather's War' from Murray Leinster.  The kids are hooked up to a circuit to conserve time/resources, so they only have to deal with as many at any time as they want, and all the ones on the circuit supposedly get the benefits of attention and getting played with and such.  Doesn't really work that way, though.

Comment: @mantis: Much like my comment above the time frame doesn't match, although I think it might be for the best if we added ours as answers with the caveat that the time frame indeed does not match. That way, people will find it in the future.

Comment: @mantis: I added my answer below. Do you want to do the same with PauseTime?

Comment: I added two of the answers from the comments to ensure that they're searchable. As always, if those authors would prefer to put their own answer in, I will gladly yield.

Answer (score 4):

As noted above, the time frame does not match, since it was released in 2002, but "[Back In My Day](http://dailysciencefiction.com/science-fiction/future-societies/stacey-danielle-lepper/back-in-my-day)" by Stacey Danielle Lepper is a very good match. It features a mother with a baby with an on/off switch. It's certainly something that she approves of, particularly since

> A second switch is installed on her father, who is criticizing her choice to use the switch with her child.

The switch is also already installed at the beginning of the story, which does not match the querent's description, but that's within specs.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an answer from [Mantis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/45668/mantis) from the comments so that it's searchable:

> This sounds a lot like "PauseTime" by Mary Soon Lee. It was published in 2000 though. And the mother is not enthusiastic about pausing her kid. Available online at http://lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/pausetime. Also in audio on [the StarShipSofa Podcast episode 330](http://www.starshipsofa.com/blog/2014/03/25/starshipsofa-no-330-leah-cypess-and-mary-soon-lee/).

Answer (score 0):

Also adding [Megha](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/54401/megha)'s answer in the comments:

> It reminded me of 'The Grandfather's War' from Murray Leinster. The kids are hooked up to a circuit to conserve time/resources, so they only have to deal with as many at any time as they want, and all the ones on the circuit supposedly get the benefits of attention and getting played with and such. Doesn't really work that way, though.

[Available online](http://hell.pl/szymon/Baen/The%20Baltic%20War/Med%20Ship/0743435559__32.htm)