Short story about a robot family with shut-down buttons on their backs
There was a short story I had to read in middle school about a mother and her robot child. There was a constant reminder that the child had a button on their back or the back of their neck, and in a moment of desperation, the mother pushes it and powers off her child.
There was a twist that the mother also had a button, and therefore was a robot and not truly human though she believed herself to be.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent chance to [edit] more details in your question, e.g. "I know it's not Off to the Races because I'm certain that the off switch was on the back, and it was set in the Soviet Union."

As per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139274/23243, might this be "Back In My Day" by Stacey Danielle Leppe?

Ava squeezed her house key and the front door vortex slid open. She quickly walked inside, straight to Gil's room to put him to bed, hoping her father would take the hint. Briefly, Ava touched her cheek to Gil's before setting him down in the sleep station and caressing the smooth, soft skin beside his left ear before clicking the button to OFF. Gil's eyes fluttered shut and his breathing deepened. She adjusted his thick cotton wool all-in-one around the collar and turned to leave.

....

"And another thing. Kids used to have common sense back in my day…."
Ava stood up and went to put her cup in the dishwasher. As she passed her father she reached behind his left ear and flicked the switch that his generation had been too slow to find and too scared to learn how to use.

